# visualize coordinate axes of world system in WPF 3D

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I am currently playing around with WPF 3D. I allready got a cube in my application. Now I want to visualize the coordnate axes of the world system. It should look like a coordinate system on paper with lines res. columns as axes like for example the arrows in blender.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

I can't recommend Helix 3D toolkit enough.  It is a comprehensive toolkit for developing 3D WPF applications.

If you are worried that using a toolkit will reduce your discovery of 3D or you will somehow loose control of how you want to do things then I think you will be pleasantly surprised that it actually accelerates your learning and you are in total control.

The current home of `Helix3D` is on [GitHub](https://github.com/helix-toolkit/helix-toolkit) (also available on NuGet).

Download the source.  In the source folder there is `HelixToolkit.Wpf.sln` which includes a sub project holding all the examples.  If you compile the examples sub-project and run it you are presented with >30 really useful examples.

Here is a screenshot of the example browser running that has a demo of what you are asking for; 3D grid with x,y,z vectors at the origin.

[image]

Comment: wow that sounds great. I will definitly check that out. Thank you very much